# Attempt to read property "id" on bool when trying to export pdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, laravel-10, filamentphp

i want to export data to pdf based on certain id, when i clicked on the button, it returning an Attempt to read property "id" on bool, i've tried debugging the $data variable in the controller, and it's returning the records on certain id

`PDFController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Contract;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;
use App\Models\User;
use Filament\Infolists\Infolist;

class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function downloadpdf($id)
    {
        $contract = Contract::with(['surveys', 'surveys.surveyors', 'surveys.assets'])
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->first();

        $users = User::all();

        $data = [
            'date' => $contract->selesai_kontrak,
            'users' => $users,
            'contract' => $contract
        ];

        dd($data);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('contractPDF', $data);

        return $pdf->download('ContractDetails.pdf');
    }
}
```

`contractPDF.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Contract Details</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Contract Details</h1>
    <p>Date: {{ $date }}</p>

    <div>
        <h2>Contract ID: {{ $contract->id }}</h2>
        <p>Pemberi Tugas: {{ $contract->pemberi_tugas }}</p>
        <p>Jenis Industri: {{ $contract->industries->type }}</p>
        <p>Tujuan Kontrak: {{ $contract->contract_types->type }}</p>
        <p>Lokasi Proyek: {{ $contract->lokasi_proyek }}</p>

        @foreach ($contract->surveys as $survey)
            <h3>Survey ID: {{ $survey->id }}</h3>
            <p>Surveyor: {{ $survey->surveyors->name }}</p>
            <p>Pemilik Aset: {{ $survey->pemilik_aset }}</p>
            <p>Tanggal Survey: {{ $survey->tanggal_survey }}</p>
            <p>Jenis Aset: {{ $survey->assets->type }}</p>
            <p>Keterangan Aset: {{ $survey->keterangan_aset }}</p>
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $survey->gambar_aset) }}" alt="Gambar Aset">
            <p>Harga Aset: Rp. {{ number_format($survey->harga_aset, 0, '.', '.') }}</p>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Contract.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class Contract extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'surveyors_id',
        'surveys_id',
        'pemberi_tugas',
        'industries_id',
        'contract_types_id',
        'lokasi_proyek',
        'tanggal_kontrak',
        'selesai_kontrak',
        'status_kontrak',
        'durasi_kontrak',
        'is_available',

    ];

    public function surveys(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Survey::class);
    }

    public function surveyors(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Surveyor::class);
    }

    public function contract_types(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ContractType::class);
    }

    public function industries(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Industry::class);
    }

    public function setStatusKontrakAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['status_kontrak'] = $value;

        if ($value === 'In Progress') {
            $this->attributes['is_available'] = 1;
        } elseif ($value === 'Selesai' || $value === 'Batal') {
            $this->attributes['is_available'] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

what should i do to my code? is there any changes needed?

Comment: Which line throws the error, exactly? Presumably, something you tried to get an "id" from (probably $contract or $survey, just from glancing at the code) is actually a boolean (true or false) rather than an object. P.S. When reporting errors, _always_ provide the full and exact error message, _and_ point us to the line it occurs on. Otherwise, you're basically expecting us to guess, which is not a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: `$contract->id` should be fine, but just a heads up, `->first()` can return `null`, and `null->id` would not be valid (so your code _can_ fail). `$survey->id` might be the culprit, but you have `->with(['surveys', ...])`, and neither that nor `foreach($contract->surveys as $survey)` are complaining, meaning it's a proper iterable relationship, but somewhere, your code is doing `true->id` or `false->id`. So basically what ADyson said; we need more debugging information, specifically the line of code that is triggering the error and any related code.

Comment: oh I'm so sorry, the error is occurred at line 20 in the blade view, within the foreach for survey

<h3>Survey ID: {{ $survey->id }}</h3>

Comment: and here's the debug result

array:3 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\PDFController.php:27
  "date" => "2023-11-18"
  "users" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2623 ▶}
  "contract" => App\Models\Contract {#2635 ▶}
]

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77489144/edit) and include your `Contract.php` Model, specifically the relationship definition for Surveys, should be `public function surveys()`. `$survey` (via `foreach($contract->surveys as $survey)`) _shouldn't_ be a `boolean`, since `->with(['surveys'])` wouldn't (shouldn't) work with an invalid relationship, but it's possible `$contract->surveys` is something like `[true, false, true, false]`, (or similar). You can also add `dd($contract->surveys)` in your Controller to confirm.

Comment: i've edited my question

Comment: Ok cool. So `public function surveys()` is a `hasOne`, meaning it returns a **single `Survey`, or `null`**. There is no need to do `foreach($contract->surveys as $survey)`. You either need to rename this method to `public function survey()`, then you can do `$contract->survey->id`, or change the method to be a `hasMany()` relationship, at which point doing `foreach($contract->surveys as $survey)`, followed by `$survey->id` would be valid.

Comment: `public function surveyors()` is a bad name for a `belongsTo()`, since that should only return a single `Surveyor`. You should name your methods to match what they return: Single Surveyor should be `public function surveyor()`, then used as `$contract->surveyor->name`. Multiple Surveyors would be `public function surveyors()`, then `foreach($contract->surveyors as $surveyor)`, then `$surveyor->name`. There's a huge difference between working with a single Model and a Collection of multiple Models, and you need to use iteration and direct access appropriately.

Comment: yes that solved my problem, thank you so much

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it  For more clarification, when you were doing `foreach($contract->surveys as $survey)`, it was looping (iterating) over a single `Survey` Model instance, which is valid in Laravel, but you end up looping over the public properties of the Model. If you did `foreach(Survey::first()) as $property) { dd($property); }`, you'd see `true` (or `false`). But if you did `foreach(Survey::first() as $property => $value)`, you'd see `'incrementing', true`. And to confirm, `Survey::first()->incrementing` should also be `true`. It's an annoying side-effect of Models in Laravel 